# How to count number of spans created for a given request in spring integration test

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth

**Spring boot** - 2.7.7

**Spring Cloud** - 2021.0.5

I have a spring cloud gateway application which has a filter which makes an external call and based on response mutates the original request header before sending it to the downstream service.
The app also include spring-cloud-sleuth dependencies with zipkins. In zipkins, I do see the correct heirarchy in zipkin server - 1 trace and 3 spans. (2 spans in gateway)

I was attempting to write an integration test for the same, but not sure how.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("external")
public class ExternalServiceGatewayFilterFactoryIT extends GatewayApplicationBaseIT {


    TestSpanHandler spans = new TestSpanHandler();
    Tracing tracing = Tracing.newBuilder().addSpanHandler(spans).build();
    Span span = tracing.tracer().newTrace();
    SpanCustomizer spanCustomizer = span.customizer();


    @Test
    void test() {
        span.start();
        //mock external server to reponse with 200 and dummy value
        mockExternalServer.when(
                        request()
                                .withPath("/external-service")
                )
                .respond(response()
                        .withStatusCode(200)
                        .withBody("dummy"));

        // Mock downstream test service to reponse with 200 if request header has "External-Service-Header" header key with value "dummy"
        mockTestServer.when(
                        request()
                                .withPath("/test")
                                .withHeader("External-Service-Header", "dummy")
                )
                .respond(response()
                        .withStatusCode(200));

        webClient.get().uri("/test")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();


        assertEquals(2, spans.spans().size());
        span.finish();

    }
}
```

The GatewayApplicationBaseIT is just mocking the external service and the downstraem service. The full IT can found [here](https://github.com/dhananjay12/spring-microservice-demo/blob/spring-boot-2-line/gateway/src/test/java/com/mynotes/microservices/demo/gateway/ExternalServiceGatewayFilterFactoryIT.java).
How can I test that gateway indeed creates these multiple spans?